# Dynamic layout design according to data received from web-service call

Tags: android, web-services, layout, dynamically-generated

[image]

Hi ,in my app i need to build layout dynamically.All the dimensions of views in layout i will get from web-service.In the web-service we may have different tile sizes,According on tile size we have to place the tile in appropriate position.

Can any one help me to build layout dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate different layout programmatically.
So you should have something like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
ViewGroup layoutLoaded = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);
mainLayout.addView( layoudLoaded );
```

In this way you can load all layout you want when you need.

Comment: I will get dimensions and x,y co-ordinates of view from web-service.  you mentioned R.layout.yourlayout.this layout also i need to develop dynamically along with dimensions.Any suggestions